# Rust - что такое ParentsPath и KidsPath в find_folder и как по ним можно находить путь

Tags: windows, rust

В документации не написано и я не могу найти как это работает и не понимаю, что такое глубина рекурсии родителей и детей. И как программе найти путь используя только название папки, глубину родительских и дочерних папок.

Comment: Лучшая документация — это код, тем более он не такой уж и сложный: [раз](https://github.com/PistonDevelopers/find_folder/blob/fa77f5b20179c5d3c0b068a380712ac2c25f91f8/src/lib.rs#L15-L18), [два](https://github.com/PistonDevelopers/find_folder/blob/fa77f5b20179c5d3c0b068a380712ac2c25f91f8/src/lib.rs#L103-L104), [три](https://github.com/PistonDevelopers/find_folder/blob/fa77f5b20179c5d3c0b068a380712ac2c25f91f8/src/lib.rs#L122-L156)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Благодаря andreymal, можно понять, как устроен алгоритм поиска папки посмотрев [исходный код](https://github.com/PistonDevelopers/find_folder/blob/fa77f5b20179c5d3c0b068a380712ac2c25f91f8/src/lib.rs).

Comment: Это конечно хорошо, но это не ответ. Напишите ответ так, как будто вы пишите ответ другому человеку, с объяснениями, а не просто со ссылкой.